# How can i run a background(for O and above) music in android studio even if app is closed?

Tags: java, android, service, background-process

I want to play my ringtone in my android app in background(for version O and above) even if application is closed and stop playing if i stop from my app.

I used service in my application but the music is stopped when i closed my app.
How can i achieve this ??

Here is my Service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer player;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

  
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player=MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.setVolume(100,100);

        player.start();
       player.start();
       return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and here is my MainActivity class from where I'm starting and stopping the service:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void Start(View view) {
        startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
    }
    public void Stop(View v){
        stopService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
    }

    public void go(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,NotActivity.class ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this step by step tutorial. (https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/)

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you submitted, you have never invoked the service of the player. call the functions that you have created in oncreate method that should do the trick.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//button objects
private Button buttonStart;
private Button buttonStop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //getting buttons from xml
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);

    //attaching onclicklistener to buttons
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonStart) {
        //starting service
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    } else if (view == buttonStop) {
        //stopping service 
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
  }
}
```

**note:** Create two buttons to start and stop the service

For more info check out: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-service-example/

Comment: yes it is working in N and below versions but how can I implement in above versions like Oreo and Pie??

Comment: Starting from API 26 and onwards the background applications(foreground) cannot use the start service. When you call the startService() method from the background applications simply through the IllegalStateException. [Here](https://itnext.io/migrate-your-app-to-android-oreo-e0fa794b1d21) is an article you can go through.

Comment: if you find this answer useful click on the tick mark present below the vote of my answer. thank you :)